# Subplots with only ylabel

Tags: matlab, plot, axis-labels

I am plotting some MEG time-series stacked horizontally on top of each other. Now I want no axis to be showing but I do want to print each channel number on the left side. So far I've tried this:

```
figure;
for i=1:10
    subplot(10,1,i)
    plot(1:5000,PDdata{1,1}.data(:,i)) % data to be plotted
    axis off
    ylabel(sprintf('%d',i))
end
```

Giving me

[image]

Unfortunately the `ylabel` is suppressed by the `axis off`, how can I suppress all axis options but the `ylabel`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn the `ylabel` back on by setting its visibility to `on`.

After turning off the axis, simply add:

```
set(get(gca,'YLabel'),'Visible','on')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `text` function.

```
for n=1:10
   subplot(10,1,n);
   plot(1:10,1:10);   
   axis off;
   text(0,0,num2str(n));
end
```

With `x` and `y` you can adjust the position of the text.

Comment: This answer seems to elaborate for me, especially if I'm gonna be plotting more than 10 subplots.

Comment: Yes, this will be a lot of work to manually position the text correctly for each subplot.  When I want a common ylabel across all subplots, I actually create a new, blank axes that I then hide (with `axis off`) and re-enable the ylabel as in my answer. Not very efficient for the computer, but so much quicker for me.

Comment: Ok I understood wrong your question. I thought you wanted just one Ylabel for all the subplots. @MattB gave the better solution to your problem.

Comment: This is an acceptable answer as `text(0,0...` displays a text at `(0,0)` **within** each subplot (not in the main figure). There is no further calculation.